# Android Dynamic Module Resources Sometimes Throw Not Found Exception

Tags: android

I tried using dynamic module for an extra feature for the app. When I upload it to Play store, one of my users after back to the activity (MainActivity) it throw a `Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`.

At first it run properly without any error. But when it back to MainActivity the error is occurred.

my current Gradle Version is 4.2.1

Anyone can tell me why this error happen after start another activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just know how to fix it. This is happen not because Gradle. You only need to add a new class that extend `AppCompatActivity` let's say we had class named `BaseSplitActivity`

```
open class BaseSplitActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        SplitCompat.install(base ?: this)
    }
}
```

and then, after make that class, we change every activity code in our project to extend that class. Example:

```
class MainActivity : BaseSplitActivity() {
    // your activity code here.
}
```

This is my source for fixing this [bug](https://medium.com/@imankitaman/dynamic-feature-module-android-content-res-resources-notfoundexception-fix-15213f131e7d). 
After few update don't forget to change the 
`SplitCompat.install(/* parameter */)` parameter to `base` and check if null goes with `this`